# Unable to copy using shutil

Tags: python, linux

I am using shutil.copy() to copy file form a location(say a/b/c/d/file.txt) to another location(e/f/g/h). But the problem is the command copies the file to location(i.e e/f/g/h) but the 'file.txt' is empty. I am working on a linux machine which is the slave for my jenkins, so I can't directly access the machine. Please help

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: relevant part of the code:
shutil.copy(a/b/c/d/file.txt, e/f/g/h)

Comment: @user5772321 do you have enough space on destination?

Answer (score 0):

shutil.copy(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True)
Copies the file src to the file or directory dst. src and dst should be strings. If dst specifies a directory, the file will be copied into dst using the base filename from src. Returns the path to the newly created file.

If follow_symlinks is false, and src is a symbolic link, dst will be created as a symbolic link. If follow_symlinks is true and src is a symbolic link, dst will be a copy of the file src refers to.

copy() copies the file data and the file’s permission mode (see os.chmod()). Other metadata, like the file’s creation and modification times, is not preserved. To preserve all file metadata from the original, use copy2() instead.

Comment: Already did this by looking into the documentation. It is not working.\